# Opening a file in Geany in Ubuntu from FreeBSD server terminal connection?

Tags: ubuntu-9.04, freebsd

This probably sounds ridiculous - but Im using Geany on Ubuntu 9.04. I noticed that it has a neat little terminal window at the bottom.

Would it be possible/and if so how would I set up if I could SSH onto a FreeBSD server via that terminal then open a file on the server in Geany?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet for doing that is to use [sshfs](http://fuse.sourceforge.net/sshfs.html). Using [FUSE](http://fuse.sourceforge.net/), the handy sshfs util mounts a remote server as a local fs. eg:

```
mkdir foo
sshfs name@remote:/home/name ./foo
```

do stuff...

```
fusermount -u ./foo/
```

That way, you can use geany to open the file like a conventional local file. (I'm pretty sure Ubuntu has some fancy GUI way of doing it, but all this should work from the geany VTE.)

More info on sshfs in [ubuntu](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSHFS). Have a look also at the [Geany FAQ](http://www.geany.org/Documentation/FAQ#QQuestions10)